# Deleting all but one SharedPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to clear all but one SharedPreference. If I've saved 10+, is there a better way then removing each individually? This gets a bit redundant:

```
preferences.edit().remove("1").commit();
preferences.edit().remove("2").commit();
preferences.edit().remove("3").commit();
...
preferences.edit().remove("15").commit();
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could also get the value you want to keep, `clear()`, and re-add it before commiting.

Comment: Not bad. Might go with this

Comment: I think this is the best way

Answer (score 9):

you can loop through all the keys

```
Map<String,?> prefs = pref.getAll();
for(Map.Entry<String,?> prefToReset : prefs.entrySet()){
    edit.remove(prefToReset.getKey()).commit();
}
```

then skip over the key/s you dont want to remove

Comment: I have to respectfully disagree with a point about this solution: `commit()` can be expensive, and you'd be executing it n times. It would be much better if that part was moved outside the loop.

Comment: @matiash you can always use `apply()` which first writes it to memory and then starts an asynchronous commit to disk

Answer (score 0):

You can call remove() multiple times before commit().

```
preferences.edit().remove("1").remove("2")....commit();
```

Comment: Right but that doesn't reduce the number of lines. Anything more elegant?

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this ->

```
private static void clearSp() {

    Map<String, ?> mapPref = sharedPrefObj.getAll();
    if (mapPref.containsKey("key_need_to_retain"))
        mapPref.remove("key_need_to_retain");

    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> prefToRemove: mapPref.entrySet())
        editor.remove(prefToRemove.getKey()).apply();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value you want to exclude from clear, then call clear(), then re-add it then call commit().

```
    val valueToKeep = preferences.getInt(
                VALUE_TO_KEEP_KEY,
                0
            )//getting the value first

    preferences.edit().clear()
                .putInt(VALUE_TO_KEEP_KEY, valueToKeep).commit()
```